# Iterating a function over again after each iteration finishes

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, iteration

I am struggling to code a way for a function to iterate multiple times with a 5 second pause between each iteration. Each iteration needs to be finished before the next iteration starts.

I have been told that Callback functions or Promises would be the way to go but I am very new to Javascript and am having trouble coding it.

Would anyone be able to help me out? Let's just say the function in question is called "Ineedhelp()"

Thanks

Comment: When you say that each iteration needs to be finished before the next iteration starts, do you mean to say that it needs to finish before the 5 second timer of the next iteration starts?

Comment: Promises would be useful if the `function` includes some asynchronous code, otherwise, Promises just complicate the code

Answer (score 1):

One good way to do this would put a timeout at the end of your function. For example, if you want it to iterate 5 times the following code would work.

```
var i = 0;
function iNeedHelp() {
    i++;
    alert('You\'ve been helped ' + i + ' times so far.');
    if (i < 5) {
    setTimeout(function(){iNeedHelp()}, 5000);
  }
}
iNeedHelp();
```

Comment: Or more succinctly `setTimeout(iNeedHelp, 5000);`

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, but one simple way is using setInterval / clearInterval:

```
var maxIterations = 3;
var iterations = 0;
var msDelay = 5000;
iNeedHelp();
var interval = setInterval(iNeedHelp, msDelay);
function iNeedHelp() {
    iterations++;
    console.log("in iNeedHelp, iteration " + iterations);
    if (iterations >= maxIterations) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

This will run iNeedHelp as many times as is set in maxIteration, with a pause of msDelay milliseconds in between each call.

You can find some additional info on setInterval/clearInterval here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp